# How to return only the relevant related objects in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an API such that when I give it a keyword it will return all the cinemas that have movies containing said keyword.

Right now I am using:

```
queryset = Cinema.objects.filter(movies__title__icontains = keyword)
```

My serializer is:

```
class CinemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Cinema
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'city', 'movies')
    depth = 1
```

If the keyword is "ghost" this returns the cinemas with all their movies.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Cinema",
    "city": "London",
    "movies": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": Ghosts

        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": Ghostbusters
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": Star Wars
        }
     ]
```

Is there a way to return the cinemas and only the relevant movies (Ghosts and Ghostbusters)?

Comment: You could try this, **`queryset = Cinema.objects.filter(movies__title__icontains = keyword)`**

Comment: Noted and edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a [**`Prefetch`** object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) here:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

queryset = Cinema.objects.filter(movies__title__icontains=keyword).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'movies',
        queryset=Movie.objects.filter(title__icontains=keyword),
        to_attr='matching_movies'
    )
)
```

In the serializer, we then serialize the `matching_movies`:

```
class CinemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movies = MovieSerializer(many=True, source='matching_movies')

    class Meta:
        model = Cinema
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'city', 'movies')
```

Where you implement a `MovieSerializer` to serialize the matching movies.

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm!
And if I want to filter the movies by name and for example duration, start time etc, but these fields are optional, how can I go about implementing this? I can chain more filters to the main queryset in the different if blocks, but how will this work with the prefetched data?

Comment: @Imaginaryy: you need to filter both the main queryset, so `Cinema.objects.filter(...)` as the queryset in the prefetch, so `Movie.objects.filter(..)` with the condition.